# What does it mean for a relation algebra to be simple?

Tags: relation-algebra

I am reading "Boolean Algebras with Operators part II" by Bjarni Jonsson and Alfred Tarski. On theorem 4.10 (p.132-133), they refer to a relation algebra $\mathfrak{A}$ being "simple" and proves that it is equivalent to $\mathfrak{A}$ having no ideal elements different from 0 and 1. What definition of "simple" is being used in this context? The article is in JSTOR, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

According to the definitions given in the extended abstract available [here](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~schmidt/publications/Schmidt94c.html), a simple relation algebra is one that satisfies the condition $1;r;1=1$ for every non-zero $r$, where ‘;’ is the composition operator. Apparently an ideal element is an element $r$ that satisfies $1;r;1=r$.

Comment: That can't be it his definition, since in theorem 4.10 he proves that definition you gave is equivalent to $\mathfrak{A}$ being simple.